# Bluetooth not working on Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS successful on a Raspberry Pi 4.

However I cannot get the Bluetooth to work. In settings it says no Bluetooth found - plug in a dongle to use.

I have an identical Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspian and the Bluetooth works fine. When I run Bluetooth manager it just runs and closes.

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu Server? or did you enable a desktop?  (did you use the `desktopify` (https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify/blob/master/README.md) script which enables bluetooth on pi.4 as well as other things, or do something else?)

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/bluetooth/

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156466/cannot-find-bluetooth-device-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi-3-b ? and the solution there works.

Answer (score 10):

I found an answer for this on the raspberry pi forum - very simple:
Install the pi-bluetooth package:

```
sudo apt install pi-bluetooth
sudo reboot
```

Comment: i can confirm this solution works (even in server environment)

Comment: This worked once but after updating OS to Ubuntu 20.10 (codename Groogy), the device rebooted and since then bluetooth is completely gone bonks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working following the [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156466/cannot-find-bluetooth-device-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi-3-b) but I found I needed to run the attach command twice:

```
$ sudo hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 -
bcm43xx_init
Initialization timed out.

$ sudo hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 -
bcm43xx_init
Set Controller UART speed to 921600 bit/s
Flash firmware /etc/firmware/brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd
Set Controller UART speed to 921600 bit/s
Device setup complete
```

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me in ubuntu 20.10 for raspberry pi 4 when I had removed the number 921600 from the previous answer by Ian Mercer.

```
sudo hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx
```

Comment: This also works on on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!